# splunk mysearchbar.timerange.val() datetime to UTC

Tags: datetime, splunk

I am using Splunk 6.2.X along with Django bindings to create a Splunk app.

To get access to the earliest/latest dates from the timerange picker, am using the following in my JS.

```
mysearchbar.timerange.val()
```

Am getting back a map where the values are in epoch format:

```
Object {earliest_time: 1440122400, latest_time: 1440124200}
```

When I convert them using moment using the following, I get different datetime than expected:

```
> moment.unix('1440122400').utc().toString()
"Fri Aug 21 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0000"
```

However, the time does not correspond to the values that have been selected on the time range picker i.e. 08/20/2015 22:00:00.000

Am not sure what the difference is getting caused by? Am sure tht the timezone is not the factor as the time difference is erratically not equivalent to derive using simple timezone add/subtract.

I was wondering if this behaviour can be explained as to how to get the Splunk epoch datetime to UTC would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the timezone issue by performing the following:

1. Setting the timezone of the Splunk engine to UTC in props.conf as follows:

> TZ = GMT

2. Setting up the CentOS (the server hosting Splunk) to UTC

Hope this helps anyone else who stumbles upon similar issues.

Thanks.